# Long.sum android method not found

Tags: java, android

Java Lang Long according to android documentation has a sum method.
When typing in android studio cant find the method and does not appear in autocomplete list . JDK 1_8 and JDK 1_7

Comment: you must add min api level > 23 in your graddle build file (Long#sum was added in Android M)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @ avianey said Long.sum is api 24 and above

Answer (score 3):

Right click over your project in Android Studio and go to Open Module Settings. From SDK Location section, make sure that JDK Location is set to Java 8. [Long.sum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#sum-long-long-) method support has been added in java 8 so, you can't access it if you set the JDK to Java 7.

Comment: its api level dependant

Comment: To my knowledge, if you want to work with API 24, you must set your project JDK to Java 8 anyway.